# How to call class from java file in Kotlin file

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I have created RN module to check if java and kotlin interoperability in RN. I was able to call kotlin class and methods in java but failed to call java in kotlin module.

```bash
\RNNativeToastLibrary2Module.kt: (23, 7): Unresolved reference: Demo
```

Below are codes of RN module built using kotlin and calling java class in Kotlin. Both are under same package.

I tried to open the project in android but it failed to sync Gradle and says to edit gradle wrapper properties but that does not exist in the path and there is no auto fixing shown for it.

Android Studio console.

```sh
oid\build.gradle' line: 12

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.library'.
   > Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 6.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\daemon\6.8\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

build.gradle (Module)

```gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

// add for kotlin
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"


// plugins {
//     id 'com.android.application'
//     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
// }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // added or kotlin. version varibale is from project level gradle
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
```

build.gradle (root project)

```gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" //KSR
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Java

```java
package com.reactlibrarynativetoast2;

public class Demo {
    
}
```

kotlin

```kotlin
package com.reactlibrarynativetoast2
...

class RNNativeToastLibrary2Module(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

  ...

  @ReactMethod
  fun Say(str: String) {

      Demo()  // CALLING JAVA CLASS HERE...!

      // also tried
      // val v = Demo()
      // var v = Demo()
      // var d:Demo = Demo()

      // val v =  com.reactlibrarynativetoast2.Demo()
      // Error: Unresolved reference: Demo
      Log.d("ReactNative","in Kotlin module: ${str}")
  }
  
}
```

When I call whith full package name it can't recognise the package name as well meanwhile there is no issue with kt file. I can call methods and classes from kt files.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can't use it because you haven't assigned a variable.

val demo = Demo()

Or

var demo = Demo()

Comment: yeah already tried that too. and var demo:Demo = Demo()  as well. Thanks for reminding I updated the question

Comment: by the way it says unresolved reference it does not recognisees the demo class it won't produce error if I try this on  normal app in android studio. But here we have to do everything manually so I might be missing something

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: have you import Demo class ?

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig this is not a thing to be asked I guess. If not imported, it will give error in the compiler

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle version you are using is very old and that might be and issue for you. Update the Gradle version in order to prevent the issue. I faced the same issue a week ago and resolved it this way.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2' //update this to latest version
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2" as well

Comment: Change it to 2.2

Comment: ok I used "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3" after your comment. did not work :(. But thanks for replying. You can suggest more I will try as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire `buildscript` block from your module's `build.gradle`. You already have an appropriate recent version of the android build tools specified in your project's `build.gradle`. There's no need to try to override that in the module's `build.gradle`.

Incidentally, the version you're specifying in that module file (1.3.1) is ancient history, and `jcenter()` is obsolete.

Comment: I tried this after seeing your comment but did not solve. still unresolved reference error. I removed the build folder as well cleaned using  'gradlew clean'.